# How do I exclude multiple results from a query if a condition is met in one row

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database

I have 2 tables I am trying to join:

This table shows all of the employees that meet a number of criteria for a given task/skill combination, and are therefore candidates to be assigned to the task:

| task_id | task_start | task_end | skill_id | employee_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-15 | 2020-01-20 | 38 | 1001 |
| 1 | 2020-01-15 | 2020-01-20 | 38 | 1002 |

This table shows the tasks that have already been assigned to an employee:

| assign_id | employee_id | task_id | skill_id | assign_start | assign_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16285 | 1001 | 4 | 91 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-18 |
| 16286 | 1034 | 2 | 84 | 2020-04-01 | 2020-04-19 |

I am trying to join these tables to show which employees can be assigned to a task. The business rule is that an employee can only work on one task at a time.

How can I query the assignment table for possible date overlaps, then exclude that employee from a result table showing all of the possible assignments?

For example, task 1, skill 38, employee 1001 is a possible fit to be assigned(the purpose of the first table), but after querying the second table, you see that they have an assignment with dates that overlap with the dates for task 1.

I want to produce a table that includes task_id, skill_id, and employee_id for all assignments that are possible and meet the criteria of no date overlap.

NOTE: once an assignment is made, the query will need to run again to compare it against the new data...

Comment: Did you try to solve it before?! And, what about the last note? Where assignment can be made? In website or application

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    task_id, skill_id, employee_id, max(task_end) as data_a
from
    employee a
where
    data_a > (select min(assign_end) from assigned b
        where a.employee_id = b.employee_id group by employee_id) group by employee_id
```

never test it in mysql
just perform a clue

Comment: Can you clarify here? Is "employee a" table 1? How are you joining the tables?

Comment: employee table 1,assigned table 2. you neednt join them .try the sql you will find out the result